# Verify if the following expression is true

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

**If**: $$\exists! x P(x) \iff \exists x\forall y (P(y) \leftrightarrow y=x)$$
**Then**: 
 $$\begin{split}\neg(\exists! x P(x)) \iff \neg(\exists x\forall y (P(y) \leftrightarrow y=x))\\
\iff (\neg\exists x)(\neg\forall y)\neg (P(y) \leftrightarrow y=x)\\
\iff  \forall x \exists y \space \neg (P(y) \leftrightarrow y=x)\\
\iff  \forall x \exists y (P(y) \oplus (y=x))\end{split}$$

Comment: It looks right to me.

Comment: @CliveNewstead There's a typo in your about me section. Your book looks wonderful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a misstep on the second line.  $~\neg (\exists x~\psi) \Leftrightarrow (\neg\exists x)~\psi~$ but $~\forall y~\phi \nLeftrightarrow \neg \forall y~\neg\phi~$.

Instead you should have used the duality rules. $~\neg\exists x~\phi\Leftrightarrow \forall x~\neg\phi~$. Then $~\neg\forall y~\psi\Leftrightarrow \exists y~\neg\psi$ will give the third line.

$$\begin{split}\neg(\exists! x P(x)) &\iff \neg(\exists x\forall y (P(y) \leftrightarrow y=x))\\
&\iff \require{cancel}\cancel{(\neg\exists x)(\neg\forall y)\neg (P(y) \leftrightarrow y=x)} & \quad&\forall x~\neg\forall y~(P(y)\leftrightarrow y=x)\\
&\iff  \forall x \exists y \space \neg (P(y) \leftrightarrow y=x)\\
&\iff  \forall x \exists y (P(y) \oplus (y=x))\end{split}$$

However, you did reach the correct conclusion in the end.

Comment: so the negation kinda "moves around" the expression step by step  ?

Comment: "kinda" yes. @Noodle